# Beginner SQL - use of join

Tags: sql

The scenario is this:

I have two tables: the first with a list of onlinespeakers and the second 
with rooms they are speaking in.

```
OnlineSpeaker
------------

 - ID
 - Time
 - RoomName
 - SpeakerName

Rooms
-----
 - ID
 - Time
 - RoomName
 - Location
```

The speakers are logged in OnlineSpeaker routinely.

The Rooms table is used for manually adding the location of Rooms. Each RoomName 
can have multiple locations, but it's only the latest (according to Time) that 
is valid.

I want to see each (unique) RoomName from OnlineSpeaker and the location (if it exists) 
from Rooms.

```
 RoomName   Location
    ------------------------
    403     Germany
    405     France
    506     England
```

### Edit

I have added the query that is not yet perfect. It does give a list of room names and their location. But it gives duplicate room names and locations if there is several entries for a room in the Room table. I prefer to only show one location for each room and that location should be the latest added in the Rooms table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.RoomName, b.Location
FROM OnlineSpeakers AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  Rooms AS b ON a.RoomName = b.RoomName
ORDER BY a.RoomName
```

Comment: Show us your query and explain where it's going wrong and we can point you in the right direction

Comment: So with a given speaker you want all room locations he ever logged in? Or do you want to restrict it to currently valid locations (thus not showing older room locations he had logged in to)?

Comment: Thorsten, only the valid location should show. I added a query in the latest edit, but unfortunately it shows duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the maximum time per room to find the latest, i.e. current, room entries. Outer join these to the online speakers.

```
select 
  valid_room_locations.roomname, 
  valid_room_locations.location
from onlinespeaker
left outer join
(
  select *
  from rooms
  join
  (
    select roomname, max(time) as last_time
    from rooms
    group by roomname
  ) as last_room_time on last_room_time.roomname = rooms.roomname and last_room_time.last_time = rooms.time
) as valid_room_locations 
  on valid_room_locations.roomname = onlinespeaker.roomname -- logged into that room
  --and valid_room_locations.time <= onlinespeaker.time -- provided you want only logins in this valid location
where onlinespeaker.id = 1;
```

I don't know if you only want to consider logins into the latest room location. Then you would have to compare login time with the room's "valid since time" (the  commented line).

Moreover, if it's possible a speaker logs in to a room location, logs out and logs in again, then you will get duplicates. Use `SELECT DISTINCT` in that case, as you did in your original query.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT RoomName, Location
FROM OnlineSpeakers
LEFT OUTER JOIN Rooms on OnlineSpeakers.RoomName = Rooms.RoomName
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check if this is what you need:

```
with onlineSpeaker as

(select 1 id, sysdate-10 speaktime, '400' roomName, 'speak1' speakerName from dual
union
select 2 id, sysdate speaktime, '405' roomName, 'speak1' speakerName from dual
union
select 3 id, sysdate-3 speaktime, '400' roomName, 'speak4' speakerName from dual
),
Rooms as
(
select 1 room_id, sysdate-4 room_time, '400' roomMasterName, 'Germany' roomLocName from dual
union
select 2 room_id, sysdate-7 room_time, '405' roomMasterName, 'France' roomLocName from dual
union
select 3 room_id, sysdate-6 room_time, '401' roomMasterName, 'England' roomLocName from dual

)
select roomMasterName, roomLocName, speakerName  from onlineSpeaker, Rooms 
where roomMasterName = roomName
and speaktime = (select max(speaktime) from  onlineSpeaker where roomName = roomMasterName)
```

Answer (score 1):

Write as:

```
with CTE as
(
    select Time,RoomName,SpeakerName , row_number() over (partition by SpeakerName order by time desc) as rownum
    from OnlineSpeaker
)
select CTE.Time,CTE.RoomName,CTE.SpeakerName , Rooms.Location
from CTE 
Join Rooms on CTE.Time = Rooms.Time and CTE.RoomName = Rooms.RoomName
and CTE.rownum = 1
```

Check [Demo](http://rextester.com/XJY65034) here.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is normalise your data so you have,

### OnlineSpeaker

- Id
- SpeakerName

### Rooms

- Id
- RoomName
- Location

### RoomOnlineSpeaker

- Id
- RoomId
- OnlineSpeakerId
- Time

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT OnlineSpeakers.RoomName, orderedRooms.Location
FROM OnlineSpeakers LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT RoomName, Location FROM Rooms ORDER BY Rooms.Time) 
        AS orderedRooms ON OnlineSpeakers.RoomName = orderedRooms.RoomName
GROUP BY OnlineSpeakers.RoomName
ORDER BY OnlineSpeakers.RoomName;
```

Order the `Rooms` table before joining with it, and group the results. This way you should only get those results with the highest (= latest) Timestamp per RoomName before you group them.

The last line is optional, use it if your grouping is not in the correct order.